# Does any one know how to link One UITableviewGroupedCell to a detailview and link another cell to another detailview?

Tags: xcode, uitableview, detailsview, objective-c++

Does any one know how to link One UITableviewGroupedCell to a detailview and link another cell to another detailview? I've tried everything and searched everything.

FYI: Its a grouped tableview on the fifth tab of a tabbar app. IDK if you need to know this, but its there

Answer (score 0):

you can do it in

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

first check for indexPath.section and then indexPath.row

Comment: But Could you give me an example with fake nib names and rows and such. I don't know much about Objective-c and c++.